# Using MultiValueSubChildrenNodePropertiesTransformer with CompositeFieldBuilder in Magnolia

Tags: magnolia

In Magnolia, I'm setting up a multi-field as such:

```
cfg.fields.multi("redirects").label("Redirects").field(
    new CompositeFieldBuilder("redirects").fields(
        cfg.fields.text("source").label("Source"),
        cfg.fields.pageLink("destination").label("Destination")
    )
    .transformerClass(
        MultiValueSubChildrenNodePropertiesTransformer.class
    )
)
```

But the problem is whenever I try to add something via the `Edit Page Properties` link, I'm getting the following exception:

No suitable constructor found for class [class info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.multi.MultiValueSubChildrenNodePropertiesTransformer]

Am I missing something in how this should be structured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error was caused because `transformerClass` was being called on the `CompositeFieldBuilder` instead of in the main chain

```
cfg.fields.multi("redirects").label("Redirects").field(
    new CompositeFieldBuilder("redirects").fields(
        cfg.fields.text("source").label("Source"),
        cfg.fields.pageLink("destination").label("Destination")
    )
)
.transformerClass(
    MultiValueSubChildrenNodePropertiesTransformer.class
)
```